# Как обратиться к другому bandle.js

Tags: javascript, webpack

Есть несколько Webpack сборок, они выполнялись в разных местах и в разное время, но я точно знаю какие они содержат модули. Т.е. получается, например, одно ядро с: ReactJS, Redux, react-redux, еще куча библиотек и компонент. Другие модули - прикладной модули, там страницы и бизнеслогика. Можули грузчтся асинхронно ядром. Прикладных модулей много и я не могу все собирать разом. Конечно могу экспортировать какие то переменные в window, но это не универсально. Хотелось бы иметь возможность обращаться как то так:

`import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';`

При чем `'React'` бы брался из сборки ядра, ну на крайняк так:

`'core_bundle/react'`

Как это сделать возможным?

Comment: Из всего выше сказанного явно только одно - Вы выражаетесь словами не js разработчика. Из-за этого можно лишь предположить что в одном проекте Вы и создаете библиотеки и используете их. Если это так, то библиотеки нужно собрать и подключить их так, как-будто они стороние, прописать externals в конфиге.  Если это не так, то простите, я впервые слышу в js выражение ЯДРО и не понимаю куда его натягивать.

Comment: У нас большой проект и есть свой фреймворк, мы это называем ядром. По моему логичное название )) Еще есть порядка 30 немаленьких SPA модулей, которые используют этот фреймворк. Каждый проект билдится отдельно и тянет кучу зависимостей из package.json. Т.к. сейчас вышеописанная проблема не решена, каждый модуль перезагружает страницу и по новой все тянет (один фиг в каждой сборке есть все, а тут почистить страничку можно). Externals не поможет т.к. количество и состав экспортируемых модулей ядра постоянно меняется.

Comment: Вот послушайте себя - У нас большой проект.. Каждый проект билдится отдельно...30 немаленьких SPA модулей...каждый модуль перезагружает страницу...   

Для меня, как для человека который сильно связан с js, это звучит как ребус! Вы webpack на сервере в риалтайме чтоль додумались использовать?

Comment: Странно что ты сильно связан с JS, раз не слышал что SPA приложение иногда могут делить на ядро и прикладную часть! Ребуса тут нет, есть вопрос: как обратиться к модулю внутри бандла А из модуля бандла Б, явно не используя экспорты в бандле А, лучше если обращение (import ... from ...) будет содержать оригинальный путь, который использовался для обращения к модулю внутри бандла А.

Comment: То что я понимаю из одной части Ваших слов не вяжется с другой. И я не могу дать ответ так как не понимаю Вас до конца. Вы просите как обратится из модуля бандла А из модуля бандла Б... Я раз пять перечитывал пока, как мне кажется Вас понял. Вам нужно вынести общий код из всех точек входа?

Comment: Общий код уже вынесен и назван ядром ) По сути, вынос общего кода, это стандартная фича вебпака, если все делается одной сборкой. А у меня сборок несколько.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `webpack 2.2` нашел плагин `DllPlugin` (наверное он раньше появился). Этот плагин, входящий в сам webpack, позволяет при билде бандла создавать его манифест и при билде другого бандла его использовать, т.о. можно обращаться к библиотекам 
из другого бандла.

Как я понял, этот плагин ничего не говорит как грузить эти бандлы, т.е. это на ваших плечах. [Вот неплохая статья с примерами](https://robertknight.github.io/posts/webpack-dll-plugins/)